# achieve non copying swap function

Tags: c++, move

I want to create function like:

```
void func(sample &a){
    sample b();
    std::swap(b,a);
}
```

problem is that always when I use swap then copy constructor is used and destructor is applied on temporary object used in swap function.

Is there possibility to achieve non copying swap?

Comment: Add a proper move constructor and move assignment operator to `sample`. See "rule of 5". Also `sample b();` is a function, see "most vexing parse".

Comment: You can specialize `std::swap` for your own type, or provide an implementation of `swap` in your type's namespace and call it via ADL.

Comment: `a = sample();` seems more appropriate BTW. `a.clear()` would be even better I think.

Comment: What you wan't is not really possible,  You need a object to store the state of the object you overwrite.  Sometimes, if it numeric data, you can do it without a temporary but all the math needed to do that makes the function slower than just making a copy.  If you want to avoid copies and you have C++11 or higher then make a move constructor and move assignment operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++11 solution to your problem is to provide a move constructor and move-assignment operator in your `sample` class. Then, `std::swap` will use move rather than copy operations, which should be more efficient (you'll still see the destructor being called, but this will usually be on an "empty" object and should be very cheap).

Generally, if you're writing your own copy constructor and copy assignment operator then you also need to write a move constructor and move assignment operator (as well as a destructor of course) -- this is the "rule of 5" in C++11, which expands on the "rule of 3" known from C++98. For example, consider this (bad) example class which manually manages memory (N.B. this is just an example for exposition, in real life use `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` rather than doing this):

```
class example {
public:
    example() 
        : ptr{new int[1024]}
    {}

    example(const example& other)
        : ptr{new int[1024]}
    {
        // Copy other's member array
        std::copy(other.ptr, other.ptr + 1024, ptr);
    }

    example& operator=(const example& other)
    {
         if (this != &other) {
             std::copy(other.ptr, other.ptr + 1024, ptr);
         }
         return *this;
    }

    ~example()
    {
        delete[](ptr); 
    }

    example(example&& other)
        : ptr(other.ptr) // "steal" other's ptr
    {
        other.ptr = nullptr;
    }

    example& operator=(example&& other)
    {
        std::swap(ptr, other.ptr);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int* ptr;
};
```

Now, when you `std::swap` two `example`s, the swap function will use move operations and no additional allocations will take place, just some (cheap) pointer swaps, and a no-op call to `delete[](nullptr)`.

Answer (score -1):

Your function swaps `a` with a default-constructed object. If this is the intended semantics just do

```
a = sample();
```

and provide move constructor and assignment as you see fit.